# please, i want a similar code to draw this figure with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts, workflow

[image]

please, i want a similar code to draw this figure with tikz

Comment: what you try so far? here on site are many solutions for similar diagrams ... I took a liberty and correct tags by which you will able more easily find ideas how to write code for such diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you a start. I did not have the passion to punch in texts from a screen shot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[item/.style={draw,thick,text width=5cm,on
chain,join,align=center}]
 \begin{scope}[start chain=going below,nodes=item,every
 join/.style={-latex,thick}]
 \node {blah blah};
 \node {blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah};
 \node {blah blah blah blah};
 \node {blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{I am a caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you help me to add title of this figure .

Comment: @lamamrakais I added a caption.

Comment: comment ajouter une caption !!

Answer (score 1):

A small variation of @marmot answer (without `scope`, used `arrows.meta` library, defined `node distance` for smaller distance between nodes):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                chains}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm,         % <---
      start chain = going below,
every node/.style = {draw, semithick, 
                     text width=5cm, align=center,
                     on chain,
                     join= by {-{Triangle[angle=60:2pt 2]},thick}} % <---
                       ]
\node {blah blah};
\node {blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah};
\node {blah blah blah blah};
\node {blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about writing 100 additional answers of this type, each of which uses a slightly different pgf key?

Comment: @marmot, :-). In such cases you need to define different nodes styles for each answer. Of course, if  one image (what is not case in question) need different nodes style, than `every node` can be used only as `append style` for some common node style features (not recommend, though).